# Placing a shared web components inside npm package

Tags: angular, npm

we have a group of components that we want to use on different websites. And we want these components to have routing from different websites.

We used [ng-packagr](https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packaged) to package these components but we are having many issues with this approach and many times using ng build --prod is not working.

Is there another way to handle this situation? To have the components placed in a shared way and reused without the need to a package?

Thanks in advance.